# Displaying a Public Twitter Timeline?

Tags: android, twitter

The requirement I have is to:

> display the last 20 *native* tweets of a public Twitter timeline without the need of any authentication, period!

I read about different approaches to do that but I *honestly* don't know what is best for me. Some uses search functionality, others prefer GET requests and parsing .json responses. And some suggested using [twitter4j](/questions/tagged/twitter4j) and others uses public RSS feeds!

I have no experience in Twitter API and Twitter4J. This is my first twitter-based app. Any suggestion in which approach will fit my needs?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried RSS first then I read about those approaches. the RSS approach seemed very easy to me but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: If you want to show public timeline of any particular user then use Twitter 4j

Comment: Will I need to make the user to authenticate my app if I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mohit Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706204/mohit-verma), I used Twitter4j. It was easier than I thought and I did need to authenticate the user.

Thanks to all.